# How to add a custom order in gulp-inject js files

Tags: angularjs, gulp, gulp-inject

I'm having trouble adding js files in a specific order for my angular project.

for eg. I have 2 files `app.modules.js` and `app.routes.js`

When I use gulp, it loads `app.modules.js` first. This won't work for me. I want my `app.routes.js` to be loaded first.

I searched for an answer and came up empty. Please help.

Comment: gulp-inject has [a section in documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-inject#injecting-angularjs-scripts-for-development) describing how to use it with angular.

Comment: @AdrianFaciu  I have seen that. But it will only order the core angular files right ?

Answer (score 2):

Using [gulp-inject](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-inject) I think you should do the following:

in the HTML define 2 inject-sections

```
<!-- inject-routes:js -->
<!-- endinject -->
<!-- inject-modules:js -->
<!-- endinject -->
```

And on the gulpfile.js perform the following:

```
gulp.src('index.html')
.pipe(inject(gulp.src('app.routes.js', {read: false}), {name: 'inject-routes'}))
.pipe(inject(gulp.src('app.modules.js', {read: false}), {name: 'inject-modules'}))
.pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
```

This will put each file in the desired location.
of course, you can use wildcards to make it work for multiple combinations.